# Creating swimlanes using javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to create a javafx application that displays swim lanes (http://www.modernanalyst.com/Portals/0/images/Swimlane%20Diagram.jpg) and I want to drag and drop different objects (rectangles, rounded rectangles etc.) on it. javafx has a drag 'n drop feature: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm but this lets the user to drop the objects everywhere on the screen. I want them to be aligned on a specific grid, so that they are e.g. centered in the lanes.

What is the best way to do this? Using a list?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky.  Perhaps start with a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) and see how far that gets you.  If you want a more specific API, you could subclass Pane to create your own layout manager for this task.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/10934336) is a little different, but related, and might give you a start.